# Parallelism with Matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, parallel-processing, pycharm, seaborn

I have a features file and I would like to display each feature versus each other, but as they are many I separate the plot per feature, so one feature versus all the others per plot. As it is very slow, I parallelized it, and I have this code.

```
def DrawPlots(Features, FeatureNames, ...):
    feature1 = FeatureNames[Column]
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(...)
    for j in range(length):
        if Column != j:
            feature2 = FeatureNames[j]
            ...
            plot = seaborn.scatterplot(data=X, x=feature1, y=feature2, ax=axs[...])

    fig.savefig("Test " + str(Column) + ".png", dpi=150)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Features = pandas.read_csv("...csv")
    ColumnNames = list(Features.columns)
    ...
    Threads = []
    startime = time.time()
    for i in range(5):
        #DrawPlots(Features, ColumnNames, i, ...) # When not parallelized
        thread = threading.Thread(target=DrawPlots, args=(Features, ColumnNames, i, ...))
        Threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
        print(str(i) + ' running.')

    for t in Threads:
        t.join()

    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - startime))
```

This code works as expected when I run it from PyCharm:

```
0 running.
1 running.
2 running.
3 running.
4 running.
--- 118.35315799713135 seconds ---
All done.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when I start it form command line, I immediately get the following error (short version of the tread):

```
0 running.
1 running.
Test.py:25: UserWarning: Starting a Matplotlib GUI outside of the main thread will likely fail.
figs, axs = plt.subplots(...)
2021-06-25 17:05:23.080 Python[96144:2936258] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff38ded627 __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff71ccd5bf objc_exception_throw + 48
...
60  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff7307a109 _pthread_start + 148
61  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff73075b8b thread_start + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
[1]    96144 abort      python Test.py
```

Why is it happening from command line but not from PyCharm?

How can I fix it?

Is there a better way to parallelize the code to work in both environment?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use threads in that case. They will not improve the execution time significantly as the computation time is likely bounded by the CPython GIL. Indeed, threading is good for IO or blocking operation in CPython and so they are often faster, but plotting is likely bounded by the graphical-like operations generally performed on the CPU in Matplotlib. You should **use multiprocessing instead**. It should fix your issue too as Matplotlib is not meant to be used in multithreaded functions.

Note that multiprocessing introduces an overhead due to the creation of several processes and data communication between processes (IPC). As a result, one should try to create processes once (ie. not in a loop) and working on quite small data and/or perform relatively intensive operation regarding the data size. Plotting with Matplotlib is generally quite intensive so it should be fine in your case. Note that you could reduce data communication overheads with *shared-memory* if needed in some cases.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced `thread = threading.Thread` by `thread = Process`, but `thread.start()` seems to be frozen. The first process is frozen and the other ones do not start.

Comment: If you are running on Windows, you should read the documentation of the multiprocessing package carefully since additional operations are required. That being said, for sake of performance and readability, consider using [multiprocessing Pools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool).

Comment: I'm on MacOS, and once it'll work the code will be deployed on Linux.